# Will fresh installing Windows 7 Pro on SSD affect user experience on data drive

Tags: windows-7, ssd, upgrade

I have a 128G SSD for my OS (Windows 7 Home Premium) and a 1T HD for apps/doc/etc.  I'm thinking of fresh installing my OS to Windows 7 Pro on a 250GB SSD.

**IF I fresh install my OS on the new SSD, would I get a seamless experience after the installation?**  Meaning I'm still able to use the apps, play the games that's installed on my 1T HD.

Please let me know if you guys needs further detail.

Comment: I can't really think of why you should have any problems. In there any specific reason you expect there may be an issue running your software after the upgrade?

Comment: sometimes when you install apps in one drive, they still have some files installed to the OS drive.  Just wondering if that matters.

Comment: I doubt it will, Windows Anytime Upgrade (assuming that is what you will be using) is pretty seamless. It's not like a fresh install.

Comment: updated my question after seeing some comments